# RecyclerView is below toolbar

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

**Problem:** I have a `RecyclerView` and a `Toolbar` in a `CoordinatorLayout`.
The `RecyclerView` is below the `Toolbar` but it should not.

[image]

**Question:** How can I achieve that the `RecyclerView` and the `Toolbar` have one border?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"></include>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/maschinelistcontainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**maschine_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: apply margin top properties to recyclerview . android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

Comment: add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to your `FrameLayout`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your code to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"></include>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior = "@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: if you use FrameLayout as a container in the main layout and there is a separate layout which includes RecyclerView - in this case, you should add 'app:layout_behavior=..." to the FrameLayout in the main layout!

Answer (score 9):

Just add below lines to your parent layout i.e `Linearlayout` of `maschine_fragment.xml`

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

or else add this line to the Framelayout of `activity_main.xml`

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

It will work for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line to `maschine_fragment.xmlm below android:layout_height="match_parent"of Linear layout

```
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```